# Mysql 20.000 users - 10.000.000+ records - best practice

Tags: mysql

I am working on a database that will grow to 5.000+ daily users in a short time. The number of records are likely to exceed 10.000.000.

For my other database app I am using multiple tables to even the load. Something like this

```
if($ID <= '200'){ $useTable = "0"; }
etc etc
```

My question regarding the code above ([Solve logics / math in php code -> what's the best approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111615/solve-logics-math-in-php-code-whats-the-best-approach))
raised a few eyebrows regarding this solution.

The reasons I choose this setup were these assumptions:
1. Searching a table with 100.000 records is noticeably faster then searching 10.000.000 records
2. 5.000 users working simultaniously on one table gives more stress to the db then working on multiple tables

I would love to get your opinions and/or better solutions for this.

Comment: 10M records is not a lot. Are you sure have the proper indexes on your tables according to the queries you run ?

Answer (score 3):

What MySQL version do you use? If you want to evenly distribute the load like you already do with custom php code, there is [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html), for example.

Comment: +1 Partitioning is what came to my mind here, too. (When it is really needed here.) It is better to solve this using partitioning with your DBMS rather than disfiguring your db table layout and also having negative impacts to your app code. This is definitivly a job for DBMS and should not impact application code!

Answer (score 1):

I recommended sharding (partitioning, as @FractalizeR said) as a solution to your original question. That's still the solution.

It's similar to the solution you had in mind, except that the logic is handled through the database itself, and the queries are much simpler. You just carry on as normal, and let the database handle the decisions of what partition to read from.

Answer (score 0):

If you have no shared data, and so data may be separated in regions (e.g. $ID % 10), than it's a good practice. It will make index search a bit faster (realy insignificant optimisation). I don't even mention table locks - hope you do not use myISAM.

About this "5.000 users working simultaniously on one table gives more stress to the db then working on multiple tables" - it is not true, if you use row level locking engines (like InnoDB).

As far as I understand, your unshared data is something like user sessions. Why don't you use memcache for this case, instead of mysql?

Little note about FractalizeR's advice: I don't recoment to use partitioning in mysql. It works weirdly slow and has open bugs. I can post more info about it, if you are interested.

Comment: These tables only store unshared data. This data is user inputted data and can span more then 10.000 records per user.   All shared data is in a normal db structure.   The large tables are Innodb.                                                          I've read a little about partitioning now and I am a bit concerned about the complexity.

Comment: You say `All shared data is in a normal db structure`, no memcache or smth then. Your way with sarding by ID is good. If the load grows - you just insert one more mysql server. Again ask you to use partitioning with caution. In mysql internals it is written a bit askew and can become a problem. Better "partition" it manualy (e.g. inside if application).